# blockchain account has watch onl on i

Tags: transactions, wallet, address, blockchain.info

blockchain have been zero help. I need to know how I can get a private key to release my funds

I transferred funds from the exchange blockchain lost it. I had to find it myself I transferred it to imported wallets and had a watch only tag on it. I need these funds, but need a private key how do I get one

Comment: How exactly did you create the address to which you transferred the funds?

Comment: imported the wallet

Comment: I  found the wallet in an unspent account and imported it

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understood the question well. Would that be correct:

*I transfered from some exchange my funds to an address, which I [imported as watch address](https://blog.blockchain.com/2016/05/31/how-to-use-watch-only-addresses/) on blockchain.info. Now I see funds but I can not spend it, what should I do?*

If that questions is the same what is asked and user reports that blockchain.info has not helped at all, then I would assume that blockchain.info is not the owner of the address that was imported. Here is what you could do:

- To which address did you send your funds? If it is address that you somehow created with some application like bitcoin core, multibit, .... , then their application/user data folder must be still present on your pc (even if you uninstalled it). If that is the case and a wallet address you sent funds too is in ie. bitcoin core, you can export your private key if you write in the console `dumpprivkey YourBtcAddress`
- If you imported exchange's wallet address, then funds would be still visible on exchange. In that case exchange would still have your coins and could help you
- If this address has never belonged to you, then you do not have the private key and you **can not** do anything beside to contact the owner of the address.
- Bruteforce is not really a option, but in theory it is possible. However, **this is a point that you actually should forget**.

I hope it helps. I see here only 3 possibilities, address belongs to you (you can retrieve your funds), address belongs to exchange (you still could get your funds) and that it belongs to somebody you do not know and you have no private key (in that case you can not do anything to get your funds back), maybe you could ask on internet who is the owner but I doubt any repl will come.

Answer (score 0):

If you just imported the address and not its private key, then you cannot spend the Bitcoin. Each address has only 1 private key, and that private key is designed to be basically impossible to find unless you were the one who generated it. Since you do not have the private key for your watch-only address, you cannot spend the Bitcoin. Unfortunately the Bitcoin is lost and there is nothing that you can do about it.